# Inserting form data to two rows in database

Tags: php, mysql

I am just starting to learn PHP and MySQL by myself.

```
I have a form like this:
Upart1 | Upart2 | Utotal
Dpart1 | Dpart2 | DTotal
```

Its like a sports game with 2 periods and 2 teams competing.

And I have MySQL table 'test1' in database 'mydb' where is 4 columns:
    id | up_id | part1 | part2 | total

How I have this code to post data from one part of the table (Upper)

```
 <?php
if(count($_POST) > 0){
  $link = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "password", "mydb");

  if(!$link){
    echo "No connection: (" . mysqli_connect_errno(). ")";
  } 
  else{
      $statement = mysqli_prepare($link, "INSERT INTO test1(part1, part2, total) VALUES(?,?,?)");

    if($statement){           
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, "sss", $_POST["Upart1"], $_POST["Upart1"], $_POST["Utotal"]);          
            mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);         

            mysqli_stmt_close($statement);

            mysqli_close($link);
    }
  }
}
?>
```

1) How can I make MySQL write data in two rows simultaneously after pressing 'submit'? 
2) I think its better to use an array here (if I have more parts, not only two). And if I will use array how can I write 2 rows at once in MySql? Will it be multi-dimensional array?

Comment: if you used meaningful names for your columns and your form fields readers would have actually understood this question

Comment: sorry. I tried to make them as meaningful as I could.

Answer (score 0):

you can use insert query inside for loop like:
`for($i=1; $i<=2; $i++){
 **your insert query here**
}`

Comment: As I uderstand right it makes the same data to be written twice. But I need to write data from fields Upart1 | Upart2 | Utotal in one row and data from fields  Dpart1 | Dpart2 | DTotal in second row.